# How to find index of a given Fibonacci number

Tags: python, c++, math, fibonacci

I tried to use the following formula

[image: formula]

to find the index of a fibonacci number([image: text]) in a programming question and all the smaller test cases passed but some cases in which F was close to 10^18 failed. I did some dry-run and found out that if F = 99194853094755497 (82nd Fibonacci number) the value of n according to the above formula is 81. I coded this in Python and C++ which can be found [here](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7710632) and [here](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7711544) respectively. I want to know whether the formula works for every value of F or has some limitations?

Note: After doing some more tests, I found out that the code is giving correct answers till 52nd fibonacci number.

Update: The question has t test cases that's why I used a for loop. The given number F might not necessarily be a Fibonacci number. For ex- If F = 6, then it lies between two fibonacci numbers 5 and 8. Now the index of '5' in the fibonacci sequence is 4 so the answer is 4.

Comment: Unless there's a problem with floating point arithmetic, (which could be the case), this looks like a better question for our sister site, http://math.stackexchange.com/ because it's more about math than programming.

Comment: It works for every value of `F` mathematically, but floating point errors can cause problems practically. Any reason against using the O(n) dp fibonacci solution?

Comment: @Someone_Else I posted this here because the problem can be both due to floating point limitations in computer programming(due to which I posted it here) or in the formula(then, I should post it at math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @awesomeyi No problem with O(n) dp solution. In fact my final correct submission of the question was using O(n) method but I wanted to know what might be wrong in this.

Comment: So your question is, why your implementation yields 81 instead of 82? That wasn't really clear to me.

Comment: @Falko Yes. My implementation is giving correct answer till 52nd fibonacci number but above that if the correct answer is n, my code is giving n-1 as the output.

Comment: By the way, why negative votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula works just fine:

```
import math
n = 99194853094755497
print math.log(n * math.sqrt(5) + 0.5) / math.log(1.61803398875) - 1
```

Output:

```
82.0
```

A remark on your code:

- Using `int(...)` for rounding off to an integer might cause trouble if the floating point result is very close to `82.0`. Numerical issues might cause it to be slightly larger, even though mathematically it would be smaller.

Comment: The answer should be 82

Comment: You're right. I mixed something up, but updated my answer.

Comment: The question actually demands to calculate the index of t fibonacci numbers taken as input. That's why I used loop to input 't' numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I have updated my question now.

Comment: Your code prints 82.0 but if i store the value calculated by the formula and then cast it to an integer, the output is 81.

Answer (score -1):

I think your formula is causing a stack overflow because the number is too large to hold in int.

Comment: The greatest value of F is 10^18(question constraints) and because of this I declared it long long integer in C++.  I don't think that is the case here but again I am not sure.

Comment: If C++ has a double equivilant, could you try using that?

Comment: @rottenbanana, stack overflows occur when there are too many function calls on the stack.  For example, calling a function on each iteration in an infinite loop would cause a stack overflow.  Although a number being too large to hold in it's type is a valid possibility for why the problem could occur, it wouldn't be called a stack overflow.
(Sorry, but semantics matter and calling that problem a stack overflow is incorrect.)

Comment: @Someone_Else What do you mean by "If C++ has a double equivalent"?

Comment: @Shubham Sorry, that was poorly phrased on my part.  If you defined F as an int or float, have you tried defining it as a double?

Comment: @Someone_Else I just tried it, now it's giving correct output for 82nd fibonacci number but the same test case is still failing. Look here: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7876935

Answer (score -2):

F = 99194853094755497 is 84 Fibonacci number and hence the index for it is 83. Use the below script to get the correct index (integer instead of float).

```
eps = 10**-10
phi = (1+math.sqrt(5))/2  # golden search ratio
fibonacci_index = int(round(math.log(n * math.sqrt(5)+eps)/math.log(phi)))
```

Additional Info, code
See this https://github.com/gvavvari/Python/tree/master/Fibonacci_index for more detailed documentation on the implementation